# Is there a list of c++11 standard library interfaces which require exceptions enabled?

Tags: exception, c++11, std

From reading revision N3242 of the c++11 draft, it appears that some components of the standard library's interfaces (notably threading and locking) depend on exception handling.

Since I do a lot of work with exceptions *disabled*, I am wondering which library components/features will be (practically or logically) unusable without exception handling enabled?

Comment: Practically, all features are usable, until an actual exception is thrown. Then your program crashes.

If a library function can throw, this is specified in the standard, so in a way there is a list — the standard itself.

Comment: @n.m. it seems you've may have read my post using the wrong definition of 'practically': http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/practically.

if not, there is a difference in the complexity and locality of things like `std::vector.at(size_t)` versus a program/environment's threading and locking. having implemented threading and locking libraries, i can tell you that you can defend yourself against the former easily and predictably. (cont)

Comment: (cont) defending yourself from the latter is far more complex. when things do go wrong, an unhandled exception is not a solution (for some of us). i can't just ignore these errors :) thus, i can't rely on the library's threading and locking implementations because the only defence offered by the library is exceptions. in conclusion, the threading and locking interfaces are not a good fit for programs where exceptions are disabled. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is over one month old, and unanswered.

I am providing an answer which can be considered a community wiki, add to it as needed.

- `std::thread` *Section 30.2.2*. Transitive. Abstraction implemented using native implementations.
- `std::mutex`, `std::recursive_mutex`, `std::timed_mutex`, `std::recursive_timed_mutex`. *Section 30.4.1*, Intransitive if you supply your own exception free locking (via `BasicLockable`, `Lockable`, `TimedLockable`). Abstraction implemented using native implementations.
- `std::condition_variable` *Section 30.5*. Transitive. Abstraction implemented using native implementations.

note: There will be more.

Answer (score 4):

First of all (just as a reminder), disabling exceptions and RTTI are compiler specific extensions the Standard has no consideration for.

Since the Standard Library is usually tied to the compiler, it *may* be that *your implementation* of the Standard Library has been specifically designed to cope with this (and in particular, to cope with `new` returning null pointers instead of raising `std::bad_alloc`).

Therefore, what you ask for is non-sensical. Check the documentation of your own library for a complete list.

That being said, the Standard *does* guarantee that a number of operations will never throw. I don't know of any operation that swallows exceptions, I would suppose that most of them are actually safe to use as-is.

For example, all algorithms should be safe.

Still, once again, I can only recommend reading the documentation of *your* implementation.

Comment: there are common `new` variants for the purpose of avoiding `bad_alloc`. `nothrow_t` is the built in form the library provides, others (including user defined allocators) may be user defined via placement new. for collections, one can specify an allocator which does not throw: `std::vector<double, my_nonthrowing_allocator<double> >` and then vector's interface is largely usable provided you adhere to the rules. (cont)

Comment: (cont) there are complex high quality c++ programs which do not rely on exceptions. your post does have merits (+1), but i think some generalizations *can* be made in this case -- again, my examples of threading (unsafe), locking  (unsafe), and now vector (interface may be used safely if nobody's life depends on it).

Comment: @Justin: I do not say it is not possible, I just say it is not Standard. For example, even though `new (nothrow_t)` exists, a `vector` might not use it. Now, I do know that some libraries compile without exceptions, LLVM/Clang is one of them for example. However they redefined most of the utility classes too.

Comment: ah, sorry for the misunderstanding.